# React Native: elevation (shadow) and transparency on button don't work together as needed

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have an issue with displaying transparent button. I use elevation property as a shadow for android and while using transparency I get that unwanted effect of dublicacy. Any suggestions how would I use transparecy + shadow on android, other than 3rd party libs?

```
buttonStyle: {
  height: 80,
  width: 220,
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  borderRadius: 20,
  elevation: 10,
```

},

[Button display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIVHf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I hope this is what you expect.

```css
  backdrop: {
    paddingTop: 60,
    width: 320,
    height: 120
},
 
buttonTitle: { color: 'white', height: 40, textAlignVertical: 'center' },
buttonView: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    margin: 10,
    elevation: 7,
},
button: {
    backgroundColor: '#623DEE50',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
}
```

```html
   <ImageBackground
                                style={styles.backdrop}
                                source={{ uri: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/255379/pexels-photo-255379.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb' }}>
                                <View style={styles.buttonView}>
                                    <View style={styles.button}>
                                        <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Button</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </ImageBackground>
```

Comment: That kind of works, but I need that button to be transparent to the background (image).

Comment: I thought it will work too, but it doesn't give me any shadow at all.

Comment: @Lummy did you find a solution please? :( I am stuck at this too :(